# SQL Statement Not Returning Anything

Tags: php, mysql-error-1064, mysql

I have a form whereby users are required to anwser their own security question before proceeding further. my form is as follows:

```
    <form action="securitychecked.php" method="post">

<table width="70%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT secret_question FROM public WHERE active = 'activated' AND ni = '". $_SESSION['ni']."'")
or die(mysql_error()); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo '<hr><h4>This Person Has Not Setup A Security Question</h4><hr> ';
    } else {

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

        echo  $info['secret_question'];

}
    }?></td>
    <td><span id="sprytextfield1">
      <input type="text" name="secret_answer" id="secret_answer" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*</span></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><br /><input name="" type="submit" value="Continue" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

my php code looks like this:

```
    <?php

$secret_anwser=$_POST['secret_anwser'];

$secret_anwser = stripslashes($secret_anwser);
$secret_anwser = mysql_real_escape_string($secret_anwser);

$sql="SELECT secret_anwser FROM public WHERE secret_anwser ='$secret_anwser' AND active = 'activated' AND ni = '". $_SESSION['ni']."'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count==1){
header("location:votenow.php");
}

?>
```

I have a table called public and a field called 'secret_anwser' but i keep on getting a blank page even with the right value being entered. can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: [Debugging techniques for PHP programmers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/)

Comment: Did you select the right catalog (db name) to use when executing your sql stmt?

Comment: yes i did select the right db name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess all the **`secret_anwser`** in your PHP are typo's.

At least the fields name is **secret_answer** but you try to get **`$_POST['secret_anwser'];`** , you'll never find anything inside the DB.

The names of the DB and the table also may be wrong.